# 2-column UL with odd number of list items in the right column?

Tags: css

I have a ul using `columns` to split it into two columns. The list has an uneven number of list items but I would like for the odd number of list items to be in the right column instead of the left. Is this possible?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  columns:2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Left</li>
  <li>Left</li>
  <li>Right</li>
  <li>Right</li>
  <li>Right</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a pseudo element when the number is odd to make it even and force the second column to have more items. Both will have the same number of items but the first one will contain the pseudo-element.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  columns: 2;
  margin: 10px;
}

ul:has(> :last-child:nth-child(odd))::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height:.1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Left</li>
  <li>Left</li>
  <li>Right</li>
  <li>Right</li>
  <li>Right</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Left</li>
  <li>Left</li>
  <li>Right</li>
  <li>Right</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it won't work on Firefox for now due to the lack of support of :has()